# Java Switch with return statement

Tags: java, command-line, switch-statement

I need to return the value of a number input by the user from the command line.

e.g.:

```
java Test 5
```

1 = January

2 = February etc...

I have tried using a switch statement, however, I receive an output:

```
May
5
```

when the input from command line. I'm not sure why this is.

The output should be:

```
/May
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
class theDate {

private int month;


public theDate(int theMonth){

    month = theMonth;

}

public theDate(){

}

public int getMonth() {

    switch (month) {

      case 1: System.out.println("January"); break;

      case 2: System.out.println("February"); break;

      case 3: System.out.println("March"); break;

      case 4: System.out.println("April"); break;

      case 5: System.out.println("May"); break;

      case 6: System.out.println("June"); break;

      case 7: System.out.println("July"); break;

      case 8: System.out.println("August"); break;

      case 9: System.out.println("September"); break;

      case 10: System.out.println("October"); break;

      case 11: System.out.println("November"); break;

      case 12: System.out.println("December"); break;



        }

        return month;

}



public String getDate(String[] datePartsObj) {


        month = Integer.parseInt(datePartsObj[0]);


        return "/" + month;

    }

}


public class Test {

private MyDate myDateObj;


public Test(){

}


public static void main(String [] args) {

    String[] datePartsObj;
    datePartsObj = args[0].split("/");
    int month = Integer.parseInt(datePartsObj[0]);

    theDate myDateObj = new theDate(month);

    System.out.println(myDateObj.getMonth());

    }

}
```

I'm very new to Java so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you meant to write `month = theMonth;` inside the constructor, not the other way around.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem question has been updated!

Comment: You have to return a `String` if you want to get an output like `\May`... Currently, your method `getMonth()` returns a number, an `int`...

Comment: OK, so in the `getMonth` method, you print the name of the month.  The method returns the number of the month.  Then you print that returned value inside `main`.  That's why you're seeing both.

Comment: case 1: return "January"; ... seems more like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to return the name of the month by checking a given number.

You have to change the method to return a `String` and not an `int`, then you can directly return the name in the matching `case`, like this:

```
public String getMonth() {
    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        // print the name of the month
        System.out.println("January");
        // and return it... same for ever other month
        return "January";
    case 2:
        System.out.println("February");
        return "February";
    case 3:
        System.out.println("March");
        return "March";
    case 4:
        System.out.println("April");
        return "April";
    case 5:
        System.out.println("May");
        return "May";
    case 6:
        System.out.println("June");
        return "June";
    case 7:
        System.out.println("July");
        return "July";
    case 8:
        System.out.println("August");
        return "August";
    case 9:
        System.out.println("September");
        return "September";
    case 10:
        System.out.println("October");
        return "October";
    case 11:
        System.out.println("November");
        return "November";
    case 12:
        System.out.println("December");
        return "December";
    // for any number less than 1 and greater than 12 throw an exception
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid month number");
    }
}
```

Comment: No real need for the println statements, is there?

Comment: @Stultuske no, that was just taken from the code in the question... It is not necessary, of course...

Comment: @deHaar is it possible to print the name of the month whilst keeping the method return an Int? I have a UML diagram that explicitly says that getMonth() must return int

Comment: @Noods sure, but then you have to determine the name in a different method. Otherwise, there is the possibility of giving this class a `private String monthName`, for example and set that in every `case`, too, in order to have it available when needed. But we don't know your UML diagram... Don't know if that's allowed or desired.

Comment: @deHaar thank you very much for that, you helped a lot. Is there any way I can get in contact with you if I have any further java related questions?

Comment: @Noods There is a chat here... I think it is more appropriate to as a public question instead of directly asking a single user. But feel free to ping me on chat if you think it's necessary. May take me a while to reply then.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire workflow has 2 print statements getting executed.
One inside `getMonth()` method(which is printing "MAY"),and other in `main()` method(which prints 5)

What you need to do is change the return type of `getMonth()` from `int` to `String`

```
 public String getMonth() {

    switch (month) {

      case 1: return "January";

      case 2: return "February";

      case 3: return "March";

      case 4: return "April";

      case 5: return "May";

      case 6: return "June";

      case 7: return "July";

      case 8: return "August";

      case 9: return "September";

      case 10: return "October";

      case 11: return "November";

      case 12: return "December";

        }

        return "Invalid Month";

}
```

This way, your workflow is going to have a single print statement in main method.